# Truncate results from a calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am trying to truncate or round a percentage from the result of calculated column.

```
select DISTINCT woo.si_number, woo.bill_name,  max (wts.est_hours) *70.00 +  sum (DISTINCT                  wob.unit_price ) as total,  
truncate (max (wts.est_hours) *70.00  +  sum (DISTINCT wob.unit_price ) - sum (DISTINCT    stk.unit_cost))  / (max (wts.est_hours) *70.00 +  sum (DISTINCT wob.unit_price )) as percentage 
                                           
                                           
from wo_operation woo join wo_bom wob on wob.woo_auto_key = woo.woo_auto_key
                  join stock stk on stk.pnm_auto_key = wob.pnm_auto_key
                  join wo_task wot on wot.woo_auto_key = woo.woo_auto_key
                  join wo_task_skills wts on wts.wot_auto_key = wot.wot_auto_key
                 
                  
             
where stk.historical_flag = 'F' and                     
  woo.si_number = 'WB6222'
group by woo.si_number, woo.bill_name
order by woo.si_number
```

The results show many decimal places and only need 2.

```
B6222   Company Name      1711.63        0.4693829858088488750489299673410725448841
```

Jeff

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicate rows.

Comment: `round` the result of the calculation

Comment: `truncate()` is not a thing in Oracle. Are you sure that's the database you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your expression:

```
truncate (
    max (wts.est_hours) * 70.00  
    + sum(DISTINCT wob.unit_price) 
    - sum(DISTINCT stk.unit_cost)
)  / (
    max (wts.est_hours) * 70.00 
    +  sum(DISTINCT wob.unit_price)
) as percentage
```

You (seem to) want the truncation around the whole computation rather than on the numerator only. So:

```
trunc (
    (
        max (wts.est_hours) *70.00  
        + sum(DISTINCT wob.unit_price) 
        - sum(DISTINCT stk.unit_cost)
    )  / (
        max (wts.est_hours) *70.00 
        +  sum(DISTINCT wob.unit_price)
    ),
    2
) as percentage
```

Notes:

- `truncate()` is not a thing in Oracle.
- `trunc()` is not a rounding function: it simply removes the additional digits. If you want to round... use `round()` instead.
- `sum(distinct ...)` is a quite original thing to use; it is impossible to tell if that's really what you want from your question only... I might just suggest to not use that unless you really know why you are doing so.
- `select distinct` is unnecessary when a `group by` clause is present

Comment: Thanks guys, Trunc worked I really did not have the syntax to complete it with all of the brackets.  The distinct had to be in some due to multiple stock lines.